# How to change target platform to Windows Phone 8.0 in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

When creating a new project (C# -> Windows 8 -> Windows Phone) the target platform is automatically set to Windows Phone 8.1.

How can I change it to Windows Phone 8.0? In the preferences there is not option to do so, nor when creating the project.

[image: Project options]

Comment: That wasn't possible in VS2013, surely it isn't possible in 2015RC either.  Phone operating system versions have the life expectancy of a mayfly.  Phones get automatically updated when a new version is available.  Not unlike the way Windows 8.0 got updated to 8.1 on desktop machines.  You did not explain why you thinking you need Phone 8.0

Comment: It was possible in VS 2013: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0xnb0dm3zxtmkz/vs2013_select_plattform.png?dl=0

Comment: That's not generally available, you probably had VS2012 installed on your machine.

Comment: I probably had it installed at some point. But at last I uninstalled "everything" (as far as VS-Uninstallers do that), deleted the `Package Cache` folder and installed VS2015. Now I reinstalled 2013, where everything works again.

Comment: There is also the listing in [Visual Studio 2015 RC Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx) where it explicitly lists "Windows Phone 8 apps" as well as "Windows Phone 8.1 apps"

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible because you created a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app. You need to create a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app (C# -> Windows 8 -> Windows Phone -> Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)).